# Django filter. What is more efficient - .filter(date__range) or .all() and filter via Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, memory-management

I have quite a large database table (1M+ rows) that experiences issues when filtering results in Django.

Currently the filter logic is the following:

```
results = Result.objects.filter(date__range=(date_from, date_to))
for result in results:
    # do stuff
```

On some periods it causes a crash (probably due to memory exhaustion)

I am wondering, would it be more efficient replacing it with the following:

```
results = Result.objects.all().order_by('-id')
for result in results:
    if result.date > date_to:
        continue
    if result.date < date_from:
        break
    # do stuff
```

In theory, since .all() creates a lazy QuerySet, it might perform better than range filtering in database with 1M+ rows.
Also would be interesting to know about memory consumption in both cases.

Maybe there is another solution how to do it more efficiently and in constant memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In theory, since `.all()` creates a lazy QuerySet, it might perform better than range filtering in database with 1M+ rows. Also would be interesting to know about memory consumption in both cases.

A QuerySet is lazy in the sense that it will only retrieve the objects if necessary, but once it has to do that, it will fetch *all* items. Not only `.all()` is lazy by the way, *all* `QuerySet`s are lazy, so if you define a `Result.objects.filter(…)` queryset, that `QuerySet` is lazy as well.

But regardless how it is implemented, filtering at the database side is more efficient, since databases are designed to do this, and it results in less *bandwidth* from the database to the Python/Django layer.

In case there are memory issues, it likely means that your `QuerySet`, even if filtered, is too large to store in memory. You can work with the [**`.iterator(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) to load batches of items that then can be processed:

```
results = Result.objects.filter(date__range=(date_from, date_to)).iterator()

for result in results:
    # …
    pass
```

If will each time load a *chunk* of records into memory that then can be processed. If you do not store the items (for example in a list), then Python can reuse the memory for the next chunk.

Comment: I would mention the unsaid fact that `.filter()` also gives a QuerySet and is similarly lazy as `.all()` is :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Great! I guess this is what I wanted to get - having an iterator that will do fetch with chunks. Will implement and let you know if it solved the issue. Thank you for a quick answer!

Comment: @EgorWexler: but the `.iterator()` already does that. This will load the data in chunks, and feed these to the iterable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I wasn't familiar with `.iterator()` before. So that mentioned that it was indeed what I was looking for  Now need to try it in the environment with this big dataset

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `iterator()` definitely improved the situation! However, when there are some longer periods taken - it's still being killed... Probably need to figure out something else.

Comment: @EgorWexler: if it is possbile, you might want to make smaller "chunks" of datetime ranges, and thus work with different queries.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, this is exactly what I am doing now  splitting the longer period into smaller ones in Python beforehand and then iterating through them